# Other way to put a path in quotes when using DirectoryInfo?

Tags: c#, registry, quotes, directoryinfo

I'm currently working with `reg.exe` and I'm creating a process with `reg.exe` as the `Process.FileName`.

When I try to execute reg.exe like following

```
REG EXPORT HKLM\\SOFTWARE\\Intel\\IntelAMTUNS D:\\Backups\\Test.reg
```

everthing works fine.

But as soon as I try to execute it like this

```
REG EXPORT HKLM\\SOFTWARE\\Intel\\IntelAMTUNS D:\\Backups\\Backup folder 1\\Test.reg
```

nothing happens - and I know why! The target path isn't put in quotes. As soon as I do that everything works fine again.

My problem now is that I'm handling all my file and folder paths as instances of `DirectoryInfo`. When I pass the path with quotes as a string, e.g. like that

```
DirectoryInfo targetFolder = new DirectoryInfo("\"D:\\Backups\\Backup folder 1\\Test.reg\"")
```

I instantly receive an exception telling me that *the given path's format is not supported*.

Is there any way to put the path in quotes and still work with DirecotryInfo?
I really need to put my path in quotes - otherwise the command won't work.

Here's some example code:

```
DirectoryInfo backupPath = new DirectoryInfo("D:\\Backups\\Backup folder 1\\Test.reg");

Process process = new Process();
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();

startInfo.FileName = "reg.exe";
startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
startInfo.Arguments = "REG EXPORT HKLM\\SOFTWARE\\Intel\\IntelAMTUNS " + backupPath.FullName;

process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
process.WaitForExit();
```

When I run this code, nothing happens - nor errors or exceptions. The .reg file itself isn't created either.

When I try to run it like this

```
DirectoryInfo backupPath = new DirectoryInfo("\"D:\\Backups\\Backup folder 1\\Test.reg\"");

Process process = new Process();
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();

startInfo.FileName = "reg.exe";
startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
startInfo.Arguments = "REG EXPORT HKLM\\SOFTWARE\\Intel\\IntelAMTUNS " + backupPath.FullName;

process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
process.WaitForExit();
```

I'm getting a `System.NotSupportedException` telling me "*The given path's format is not supported.*" But I actually need to put the path in quotes - otherwise the command itself won't work...

Comment: Arn't you missing a closing quote in the path?

Comment: Edited and also added the closing quote!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding quotes in the wrong place: constructor of `DirectoryInfo` will strip them anyway to normalize the path, so you can skip adding them:

```
var backupPath = new DirectoryInfo("D:\\Backups\\Backup folder 1\\Test.reg");
```

You can force quotes around the path when you add `backupPath.FullName` to the arguments, like this:

```
startInfo.Arguments = "REG EXPORT HKLM\SOFTWARE\Intel\IntelAMTUNS \"" + backupPath.FullName + "\"";
```